# How I can remove this Ingersoll window bolt?

Tags: windows, security, bolts

I have a small window with security bolts which have become rusted and unusable. However, I can't see how to remove them without forcing them off and damaging the wood. Anyone seen these types before and / or know how to remove properly? I scratched away some paint and can see the make 'Ingersoll security'.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the underside of the bolt?

Comment: yep. Couldn't see anything obvious but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try tapping it with a hammer towards the window frame. I bet it's on a clip that's designed so that it can't be installed/removed without having the window out of the frame. You have enough wiggle room there to test the hypothesis.

Comment: Is this a casement window?

Comment: If all else fails, just slide a hacksaw blade behind it and start cutting toward the jam. You'll probably take off some paint or mark the wood a bit, but it should be easy to repair (certainly easier than ripping it out with a prybar).

Comment: The clearance makes me speculate that it might simply have a single screw on the back, and if you open the window a little and start turning it counterclockwise (and move the rusty bolt every half-turn) it might unscrew - but that's PURE speculation with no specific knowledge of this hardware. We'll hope someone that knows comes along.